# Python Regex: how to capture alternative groups with OR operator

Tags: python, regex

I have to match any of the patterns `[link]` or `[title](link)` capturing the link part. For the first pattern in python I'd use:

```
s = "[link]"
re.match(r'\[(.*?)\]', s).group(1) # -> 'link'
```

and for the second pattern:

```
s = "[text](link)"
re.match(r'\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)', s).group(1) # -> 'link'
```

but if I want to match any of the patterns I had to use two different groups:

```
    re.match(r'\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)|\[(.*?)\]', s)
```

The expression is tested and matches correctly any of the patterns, but the problem is that I get one pattern in group 1 and other in group 2.
Do I have to check which of the groups has any content or is there another way?

Comment: Use `r'\[(.*?)](?:\((.*?)\))?'`, you will have the values you need in Group 1 and 2 (Group 2 may be None). BTW, even with your regex, if you get the two groups, you know one of them is always empty, that is why you may drop the one that did not match. With PyPi regex module, you might use `(?|\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)|\[(.*?)\])` though to get both groups into Group 1.

Comment: See [demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqtYwVZBKTonMy87VomroCgzr0QDLKGXm1iSnKFRpK5hXxMTradlHxujoQGkNGM0gXwwK1ZTXUehWFMvvSi/tEDDUFNTQVlB105BHWSYOhfU5JLUipJYDZCQJsXm//8PAA).

Comment: You can use the following regular expression, which does not have capture groups: `r='(?<=\[)[^\]\n]+(?=\](?!\())|(?<=\]\()[^\)\n]+(?=\))'`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9JnBo/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland This regex of yours does not meet the same requirements as in the original pattern.

Comment: hey unclear `[ggg]` vs `[ggg](ggg)` if don't care why alternate, does no good

Comment: The regex I gave above assumes you can use a single match rather than one or two capture groups. `[^\]\n]+` matches 1+ chars other than ']' and newlines. `(?<=\[)`, a positive lookbehind, asserts the match is preceded by '['. `(?=\](?!\())`, a positive lookahead, asserts the match is followed by ']' not followed by '(' (enforced by a negative lookahead). That clause is followed by '|' meaning "or", which is followed by matching `[^\)\n]+`. The positive lookbehind `(?<=\]\()` asserts the match must be preceded by ']('. The positive lookahead `(?=\))` asserts that the match is followed by ')'.

Comment: python has no branch reset to do it right, so dont sweat just match both `\[(.*?)\](?:\((.*?)\))?` last optional. test if grp2 matched is where link is otherwise grp1.